# Turn Windows laptop with VPN on it into a proxy?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, vpn, proxy

**Machine A**: is a laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise and a locked down version of Pulse Secure VPN client - all it can do is connect/disconnect.

**Machine B**: is a desktop running Ubuntu 22.04

They are both connected to the same local broadband router. I do have admin access for both machines and the router. I also have a remote linux server **C** that could serve as an intermediate node if needed.

Is it possible to turn **A** into a proxy so that **B** could use it while the VPN on **A** is connected?

It's not possible to get the VPN credentials to use directly on **B**, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Have you tried to use internet connection sharing? That could work, but you'll need a direct cable connection rather than through network equipment.

Comment: @gronostaj Well, the laptop is currently connected via WiFi and it does have a UTP port, however when it's connected (to router) Windows automatically disables the WiFi connection. In theory it may work if there was a way to prevent Windows from doing that. Is there? I would prefer some sort of proxy solution though.